# How to sort an array of strings containing two numbers in perl?

Tags: arrays, string, perl, sorting, numbers

I have the following array of strings:

```
Expt5_Expt12
Expt5_Expt1
Expt12_Expt2
Expt11_Expt8
Expt1_Expt2
Expt10_Expt1
Expt10_Expt4
Expt11_Expt1
```

I want to sort these strings by the first number and in second priority by the second number so that I have a list like that:

```
Expt1_Expt2
Expt5_Expt1
Expt5_Expt12
Expt10_Expt1
Expt10_Expt4
Expt11_Expt1
Expt11_Expt8
Expt12_Expt2
```

I only found solutions to sort only by the first number OR by the second. I tried some things with regex-expressions and sort-function but I didn't come to a solution.

Comment: You should show us what you have tried - so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorting by function is really easy. The function has to return -1, 0 or 1 depending if `$a` and `$b` are before or after. (As noted in comments - it can be any positive or negative value - the key point is whether the elements are before or after each other).

`$a` and `$b` are 'special' variables used specifically for perl and sorting. They therefore don't need to be declared, and are a *really* bad idea to use for other stuff in your code. But then, who uses single letter vars anyway?

So with your values:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub custom_sort {
   my ( $a1, $a2 ) = ( $a =~ m/(\d+)/g );   #extract the numeric elements
   my ( $b1, $b2 ) = ( $b =~ m/(\d+)/g );

   return ( $a1 <=> $b1     #return the result of this comparison
         || $a2 <=> $b2 );  #unless it's zero, then we return the result of this.
}


my @list = <DATA>;    
print sort custom_sort @list; 

__DATA__
Expt5_Expt12
Expt5_Expt1
Expt12_Expt2
Expt11_Expt8
Expt1_Expt2
Expt10_Expt1
Expt10_Expt4
Expt11_Expt1
```

You can make this more concise, but the essence is this:

- extract the first and second values.
- Then use the `||` operator - so that if `$a1 <=> $b1` is zero, it evaluates the second part of the expression.
- `<=>` is a 'less than, equal to, greater than' operator which returns -1, 0 or 1 based on numeric comparison. For strings you can use `cmp` to do the same thing.

(You can print these if you wish to debug how this sort is 'working' for each comparison, which is really handy if you're doing something complicated)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. It works perfect and i learned something new.

Comment: Small quibble:  `sort` doesn't care about the specific value the block returns.  It cares about its relationship to 0.

Answer (score 2):

This is broadly the same solution as others have posted, but it is made more concise by the use of `map`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = <DATA>;

print sort {
    my @ab = map [ /\d+/g ], $a, $b;
    $ab[0][0] <=> $ab[1][0] or $ab[0][1] <=> $ab[1][1];
} @data;

__DATA__
Expt5_Expt12
Expt5_Expt1
Expt12_Expt2
Expt11_Expt8
Expt1_Expt2
Expt10_Expt1
Expt10_Expt4
Expt11_Expt1
```

#### output

```
Expt1_Expt2
Expt5_Expt1
Expt5_Expt12
Expt10_Expt1
Expt10_Expt4
Expt11_Expt1
Expt11_Expt8
Expt12_Expt2
```

Answer (score 1):

use [Sort::Key::Multi](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Multi);

```
use Sort::Key::Multi qw(i2_keysort); #i2 means two integer keys

my @sorted = i2_keysort { /(\d+)\D+(\d+)/ } @data;
```